# Downloading, and loading Google analytics script locally and daily with Drupal Cron

Tags: 8, performance, cron, google-analytics

I'm using Drupal [Google Analytics module](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) for some time; It works perfectly and gives me the data I need.

Yet, since instilling it, I get the following notification on Google Pagespeed Insights:

[image]

Do you know a way to load the script locally and daily in Drupal so to prevent this notification?

Is there a way to make add a automation to Cron to download the [famous ga.js script](https://google-analytics.com/ga.js) daily from Google, load it, and then, the next day, delete it, and repeat the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been built into the Google Analytics module for sometime. In the configuration form, under **Advanced Settings** there's a **Locally cache tracking code file** checkbox. It will persist a local cached version of the JS code for day before a cron run will re-cache it.

Comment: I checked it, ran Cron, flushed all caches both in Drupal (drush cr) and in server: Google PageSpeed / Cloudflare, and yet no change was seen. Maybe it happens only after a day or I should copy the ga.js script to "Custom scripts" ?

Comment: The module [logs](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/google_analytics/tree/google_analytics.module#n495) when the script is cached so make sure its doing that as a 1st step. Everything else is up to you; between all the potential caching points (Google, Cloudflare, Server, etc.), there's no way to troubleshoot here.